# How to bind Switch state to an object in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiswitch, collectionview

In my app I have a switch and I want it to be an indicator for saving images. For now I have just a button that saves all the images.

[image]

It just makes more sense with an example

What I've tried:

```
func saveTapped() {

let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell

for image in images where cell.savingSwitch.isOn  {

...
```

But I can't access indexPath. How should I call this Save method in order to access a particular row in my collectionView? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need a way to store the "save" settings alongside each image in your table, e.g. by keeping the image and the flag in a struct:

```
struct TableEntry {
   let image: UIImage
   var save = false
}
```

and use a `var images: [TableEntry]` in the data source of your tableview.

You can then use the `tag` property of each UISwitch to store the row it's in, e.g. in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...)
    cell.switch.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.switch.isOn = self.images[indexPath.row].save
    cell.imageView.image = self.images[indexPath.row].image
    return cell
}
```

and then use the tag in the method that's called when the switch value changes to know which image is being referred to:

```
@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    self.images[sender.tag].save = sender.isOn
}

func saveTapped() {
    let imagesToSave = self.images.filter { $0.save }
}
```

Comment: Each switch is constructed as reusable for every cell, so I have problems with tags) Or is it handles the tag enumeration?

Comment: You need to set the tag after dequeueing the cell - updated my answer. Not sure what you mean by "tag enum" - it's simply an Int.

Comment: Right, that was kind of obvious. Thanks. But I have another strange bug: when I scroll up and down, so cells got reused, switch state is now assigned to a different cell. I tried to store property in the CustomCell but still I got this

Comment: You also need to set the switches `isOn` property after dequeueing. See the updated answer. Basically, due to cell reuse, you can never reliably store state in the cell itself.

Answer (score 1):

In your `CustomCell`, you can add a closure to be fired when `switch` state is changed like below,

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

   var onSwitchStateChange: ((Bool) -> Void)?

   @IBAction func switchTapped(_ sender: UISwitch) {
       self.onSwitchStateChange?(sender.isOn)
   }
}
```

then you can update your `cellForRowAt` like below,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   cell.onSwitchStateChange = { state in
     guard state else { return }

     let image = images[indexPath.row]
     // Upload Image
   }
}
```